# axios GET request returns undefined and not able to set value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to set data received from a GET request from an API using axios. But the value which is getting set is `undefined` even though `console.log` gives me the correct output.

```
const[movie, setMovie] = useState({});

  useEffect(()=>{
   const baseURL = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
        async function getData(){
          try{
            const response = await axios.get(baseURL);
            console.log(response.data); //returns correct value
            setMovie(response.data); //sets undefined to the state movie
          }
          catch(error){
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
        getData();
        console.log(movie);//logs undefined
  },[]);
```

The API request returns an object when tested in POSTMAN as well as `console.log()`, but I am not able set that to the state.

Comment: Try wrapping all the code in the effect with an additional async function, then prepend `await` to the `getData()` function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to set my state with the data received from the API request.

```js
const[movie, setMovie] = useState({
    ImgPath: '',
    Title: '',
    ReleaseDate: '',
    Rating: '',
    Description: ''
  });


  useEffect(()=>{
   const baseURL = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
        axios.get(baseURL)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
          let movieData = res.data;
          setMovie({
            ImgPath: movieData.poster_path,
            Title: movieData.title,
            ReleaseDate: movieData.release_date,
            Rating: movieData.vote_average.toString(),
            Description: movieData.overview
          })
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }, []);
```

Comment: The answer is not entirely correct. The issue is with the initial state of the movie object. In the useState hook, the initial state of the movie object is set to an empty object {}. Therefore, when setMovie is called with response.data, it is trying to set an object to an object, which is not a valid update. To fix this, the initial state of the movie object should be set to null or undefined. For example:

const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario setMovie is asynchronous, So the console.log will return the value before the updates. In your case, it will return undefined. This is because the component is not re-rendering.

More info [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value)